# Learn Python The Hard Way - Exercise 39

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples, enumeration

On Exercise 39 of Learn Python The Hard Way, lines 37 to 39 look like this:

```
print "-"*10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

I thought I understood this. I thought Python was taking the KEY:VALUE from "states" and assigning the KEY to "state" and the VALUE to "abbrev".

However, I found something strange happened when I entered the following code:

```
print "-"*10
for test in states.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (test)
```

It produces the same output as the original code.
But, it only works if you put the `%s` into the print statement twice.

Can someone explain what is happening with "test"? 
What exactly is "test"? Is it a Tuple? 
It seems to contain both the `KEY` and the `VALUE` from `states.items()`.

I have looked through some of the other questions on Exercise 39 here and I haven't found the same query.

The code is listed below (for Python 2.7)

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation

states = {
    'Oregan': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York' : 'NY',
    'Michigan' : 'MI'
    }

print "-"*10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (state, abbrev)

print "-"*10
for test in states.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (test)
```

Comment: you don't have to use states.items(), dictionary's the default iterable is key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`states` is a dictionary, so when you called `for test in states.items()` it assigns each item of the dictionary (a `tuple`) to `test`.

Then you are just iterating over the items and printing their keys and values as you would with `for state, abbrev in states.items():`

```
>>> for state in states.items():
    print (state) # print all the tuples


('California', 'CA')
('Oregan', 'OR')
('Florida', 'FL')
('Michigan', 'MI')
('New York', 'NY')
```

All the details are available online, for instance in [PEP 234 -- Iterators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/) under *Dictionary Iterators*:

- > Dictionaries implement a tp_iter slot that returns an efficient iterator that iterates over the keys of the dictionary. [...] This means that we can write
  >
  > ```
  > for k in dict: ...
  > ```
  >
  > which is equivalent to, but much faster than
  >
  > ```
  > for k in dict.keys(): ...
  > ```
  >
  > as long as the restriction on modifications to the dictionary (either by the loop or by another thread) are not violated.
- > Add methods to dictionaries that return different kinds of iterators explicitly:
  >
  > ```
  > for key in dict.iterkeys(): ...
  >
  > for value in dict.itervalues(): ...
  >
  > for key, value in dict.iteritems(): ...
  > ```
  >
  > This means that `for x in dict` is shorthand for `for x in
  >      dict.iterkeys()`.

Comment: So if I understand it, the "test" is equivalent to the "for k in dict" and when you iterate through with the print statement, you have to have two instances of %s, because "test" has both the key and the value?

Comment: Yes, the modifier `%s` is a single string, so it expects you to have 2 of them since you are trying to print a dictionary entry which has a key and a value :)

Comment: That is great, thank you so much. I tried that "test" at first as just a way to break it, and was then surprised when it gave me that result. Great help, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This "missing link" between your first and second code snippet explains why they are equivalent:

```
print "-"*10
for test in states.items():
    state, abbrev = test
    print "%s has the city %s" % (state, abbrev)
```