# invalid syntax (<string>)

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

```
# create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = [
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
    ]
```

I am learning Python from `Learning Python The Hard Way`. In `example 39` of the book, I typed the same code as shown above for creating a dictionary, even copied and pasted it, but I m getting an error
`E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 3)` and it is pointing at `:`. What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets (`[]`) are used for `list` literals. In this case, you're supposed to be making a `dict` literal (the `:` is used to separate the key on the left of the colon from the value on the right), which is delimited by curly braces (`{}`).

Comment: I changed the ( [ ] ) to ( { } ), it still shows the same error

Comment: @AnkurSatpute: You either forgot to save after editing, or saved to the wrong file, or made some other mistake not shown in your question. If your code in the question replaced `[` with `{` and `]` with `}` it would be syntactically valid; I can't guess at what other mistakes you might have made.

Comment: @AnkurSatpute: When you use brackets, the `:` is illegal, when you use braces, it's legal. `SyntaxError`s are raised at the point where the parser gives up, and until you reach the colon, nothing was wrong.

Comment: This is the snapshot of the code given in the book. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RXmc_5RPBp-4EVGMQHr7xkBvWwpP20aK/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @AnkurSatpute: Your copy is wrong. Someone else [excerpted the code correctly here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35968877/364696), as well as [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6nxu0l/learn_python_the_hard_way_exercise_39_issues/); I can't explain why yours is wrong, and a two year old excerpt is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use curly braces for dictionaries

```
states = {
    'Oregon'    : 'OR',
    'Florida'   : 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York'  : 'NY',
    'Michigan'  : 'MI'
    }
```

Comment: I changed it to { }, but it still shows the same error pointing at ' : '

Comment: Copy and paste the code into your python interpreter, and it should work. Check your file for hidden characters or tabs.

Comment: This is the snapshot of the code in the book https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RXmc_5RPBp-4EVGMQHr7xkBvWwpP20aK/view?usp=drivesdk